# Let one class do the job or separate one class into several sub-classes in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have a question related to how to define one class or design several classes and then let them corporate to finish the job. My task is:

- 1) identify some objects on the image;
- 2) analyze the features of each object;
- 3) based on the object features select those that fulfill some
  criteria.

I can define one class to do the job, for example, in C++:

```
class JobExecutive
    {
      public:
           void DoTheJob
           {
               IdentifyObjects();
               AnalyzeObjects();
               FindObjects();
            }
    };
```

Or I can define three classes:

```
class ObjectIndentifier()
{
 pulbic:
     std::vector<MyObject> objList;
     void identifyObjects();
}

   class ObjectFeatureAnalyzer()
   {
      public:
          std::vector<MyFeatures> featureList;
          std::vector<int> objSelect;
          void analysizeObjects( std::vector<MyObject> &objList);
   }
   class ObjectFinder()
  {
     public:
         std::vector<MyCoordinate> coordinatesAOI;
         void findObject(std::vector<int> &objSelect,std::vector<MyObject>  &objList);
  }
```

These three classes can be Incorporated to do the job:

```
ObjectIndentifier identifier;
identifier.identifyObjects();
ObjectFeatureAnalyzer analyzer;
analyzer.analysizeObjects(identifier.objList);
ObjectFinder finder;
finder.findObject(identifier.objSelect, identifier.objList);
```

Finally, from `finder.coordinatesAOI` variable interesting information such as the coordinates of the objects can be obtained. So my question here is: which strategy is better? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need objects for everything.  You could use free standing functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ and any OO language, a good design rule is the so named [***Single responsibility principle***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

This rule says a class is responsible of managing one aspect of the application only, and this responsability must be encapsulated by the class.
So if your application has some things to be managed, each of them should be managed by one class only, and other classes could access/use that services through aggregation.

Consider a simple compiler implementation:

```
class tokenizer
{
    std::vector<tokens> tokenize( const std::string& code );
}:

class parser
{
    backend_bytecode parse( const std::vector<token>& tokens );
};

class optimizer
{
    backend_bytecode optimize( const backend_bytecode& bytecode );
};

class binary_generator
{
    executable generate( const backend_bytecode& bytecode );
};

class compiler
{
    tokenizer tokenizer;
    parser    parser;
    optimizer optimizer;
    binary_generator generator;

    executable compile( const std::string& code );
};
```

Each class is responsible of implementing one step of the compilation process. This reduces coupling, and is more mantenible than the monolitic class equivalent, because different compilation phases could be implemented by different developers working in parallel.